# Find new stackexchange site (legal advice)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

While I was reading a question about open source licences for software on regular Stack Overflow, I saw it was closed because marked off topic.

Is there a Stack Exchange site for legal advice and licences involved with software development?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Currently not.

But there is a strong [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing) for that kind of questions. If you participate it may be launched in the near future.

Comment: This is a good proposal. Is there also a more general proposal for legal advice about e.g. project contracts/freelance contracts etc?

Comment: You can search Area51 for the keywords you are interested in.

Comment: BTW there is a http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The proposal is no longer strong. It's been deleted due to inactivity.